# Conexión rechazada por el puerto 9000

Tags: servidor, puertos, router, debian-9

Tengo el puerto abierto en el router, pero al hacer un nmap o al intentar conectarme por dicho puerto me sale que la conexión la rechaza, tampoco tengo ningún firewall instalado. La máquina es un debian 9 y es servidor web.

Haciendo un netstat no me sale:

```
# netstat -nan
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2233            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0    256 192.168.0.160:2233      79.147.25.10:50490      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.160:50926     82.194.78.250:80        TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::2233                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.160:443       79.147.25.10:50561      TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.160:443       79.147.25.10:50598      TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.160:443       79.147.25.10:50593      TIME_WAIT
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 192.168.0.160:45696     0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33981           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 239.255.255.250:1900    0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 :::34919                :::*
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Para comprender mejor cómo funcionamos, date una vuelta por el [tour] del sitio. Para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, necesitas saber [ask].

Comment: intenta hacer un netstat -nan a ver si algo lo esta usando